# How to find which add-on gives warning Visual Studio Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I installed some add-ons for Visual Studio for Angular 4, and now it gives me all kind of warnings I didn’t have before.
How do I know which add-on gives the error, so I can uninstall it?

[image: see example here]

Comment: Inactivate them one by one to see wich one causing the warning. From what i see is probably the "TSLint"-extension

Comment: why did you add TSLint extension to VS Code ? :-D . I can see prettier amongst your extensions. Using it can help eliminate some of the errors and if configured to match with your Linting configuration, more errors will disappear!!

Answer (score 0):

The error showing from tslint extension. Your project have tslint.json file. TsLint is used for checking code. You created rules in tslint.json file and TsLint extension showing your error. You can change rules according to your convenience.

Hope it will help